# Function returns boolean not string

Tags: php, mysql

What I want is to return MYSQL query in a array however my code returns a bool(true).
Here is the code from code.php

```
require('model.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$user = new user();

$row = $user->check_user($id, $password);
var_dump($row);
```

Here is the code from model.php

```
class config {

    public $dbhost = "localhost";
    public $dbuser = "root";
    public $dbpass = "";
    public $dbused = "dbname";

    function dbconn() {

        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->dbhost,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass,$this->dbused);

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {

            printf("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();

        }

        return $conn;

    }

}

class user {

    function check_user($id, $pass) {

        $config = new config();

        $conn = $config->dbconn();

        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, password, status FROM e_users WHERE id = ? AND password = ?");

            $query->bind_param('is', $id, $pass);

            try {

                $query->execute();

                return $query->fetch();

            } catch(PDOException $e) {

                die($e->getMessage());

            }

    }

}
```

I think the problem is in the `$query->fetch();` because I tried `return 'test';` and it works fine. Even return an array works fine.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `return $query->fetch();` will simply return true if the fetch operation was successful and false if it wasn't. It doesn't return the data you requested.

Comment: @TheBlueDog if it is then, how should i return it in array?

Comment: `return $query->fetch_assoc();` as per the answer posted by @peter_the_oak below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As The Blue Dog pointed out, `fetch()` returns a status flag, not the row itself. But `fetch_assoc()` will return a row.

Have a look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

If you work with `fetch`, you need to bind the variables:

```
$stmt->bind_result($mySelectedValue_1, $mySelectedValue_2);
```

Here are examples with `fetch_assoc()`:

http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

So this should work fine:

```
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: peter_the_oak and @The Blue Dog thanks for the info guys, it is now working like what i wanted.If i could i would you all a big hug :))

Comment: Glad to help. So it's a distributed, or virtual hug ;-)